# Roaming Timing Optimization

Tags: networking, wireless-adapter, wpa

Is there a way to improve reconnection timing between two RPis that communicate wirelessly through an access point?

Right now, if a connection drops on a RPi side, The roaming process takes 9 seconds to reconnect to the network.

It would be great to achieve at least a couple of seconds or even less
because I'm working on data transmissions involving real time interaction.

```
Physical interaction via sensors -> RPi 1 -> WiFi access point ->  RPi 2 -> actuation
```

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate the timing completely on the access point. Set it up so that the two Pis have a permanent lease on the AP.

This is because WiFi hotspots periodically kick out devices. There are good reasons for this like getting rid of stale connections and refreshing the encryption keys. The devices basically have a timed connection or "lease".

Most routers have the option to make the lease permanent per device or at the very least have the option to set the lease time. Set it to the highest setting it allows.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point but it doesn't answer the question: if on rpi A connection drops, wpa-roam starts to search for the network. I estimated it takes about 9 seconds to reconnect to it.. If would type manually "sudo ifup wlan0" it would take one second but rpis are running headless..

Comment: Is there a way to "speed up" the roaming process? Or to give some kind of realtime priviliges to it?